# Perl_The results of the program is not what i want

Tags: perl

The result of following program was

> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

why? it should be some file names like

> ```
> test.pl
>
> test1.pl
> ```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
opendir Hdir,".";
my @filelist=readdir Hdir;
my @tmplist=grep {
    $tmp = (stat($_))[7];
    $tmp > 1000;
} @filelist;
my @reslist = map { s/(\S+)/    $1\n/g } @tmplist;
print "@reslist\n";
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the return values of the `s///` operator, not the values it changed. If you have a new Perl, add an /r flag to the operator to make it return the changed value. If you don't have a new Perl, add something like `and $_` after the operator to make the map expression return the changed value.